# The reason why a test is undersized?

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, probability-distributions, asymptotics

Now I have a statistic $T_n$ for testing $H_0 \leftrightarrow H_1$, and I have proved that:
$$n T_n \rightarrow_d \chi_K^2$$
under $H_0$. Then an asymptotic $\chi^2$ test can be used, an asymptotic level $\alpha$ test for the null hypothesis is obtained by rejecting $H_0$ whenever
\begin{equation*}
    T_n > n^{-1} \chi_{K, 1 - \alpha}^2.
\end{equation*}
When I do simulation, however, I counter a big problem. Even $n$ is large enough (15,000 for instance), the empirical rejecting rate under $H_0$ is much smaller than $\alpha$! Does this performance means the theoretical properties of $T_n$ that I have proved may be wrong? Or there is a ubiquitous phenomenon in chisuqare testing, and it is related to some more involved questions?

Comment: This should probably be on stats.stackexchange.com rather than here.

Comment: @NeilStrickland Thanks, you are right. I just know the website you give me.

Comment: For $n = 15000$ the approximation should be quite good. So even if you change to stats.stackexchange.com you should be more explicit how you do your simulation.

Comment: @DieterKadelka Thanks for reminding me~

Comment: Can you establish how fast the convergence occurs for the Kolmogorov-Smirnov distance, for instance ? If yes, you can then check that the simulations you are carrying out are correctly implemented by performing the simulation for various sample sizes (multiples times) and checking if the distance behaves as it should.